# TYPO3 Inconsistent content detected in language "Standard"

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have updated a TYPO3 Installation with multiple Languages from TYPO3 6.2.x to TYPO3 7.6.x. On one Page a see the Hint:

> Inconsistent content detected in language "Standard" Make sure that
>   this behavior is intended and does not pose a problem for you. We
>   highlighted the problematic records for you.

But there is no Element highlighted. Normaly I see a red Border but there is none.

Did anybody have the same Experience or an Idea how I can identify the Element?

Thx

Bernd

Answer (score 4):

[Inconsistent element solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nChx.jpg)
This Problem occurs when you recently copy elements and translate them to another language.

Answer:
Edit the translated (copied) element, go to the language tab and select the original Elements title in the "Transl. Orig." dropdown. Save and close.

That should solve the issue.